# Why doesn't open the service my activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, notifications

my problem is if i click on the notification, it closes but it doesn't open the activity
Vertretungsplan. What's the problem ?

This is my Code:

```
@Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int auswertungsergebnis = 0;
            boolean weekday = checkDay();
            if (weekday == true) {
                auswertungsergebnis = auswerten();
            }
            String ausgabe = ausfaller.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(ACTION);
            registerReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver, intentFilter);

            // Send Notification
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            myNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_stat_gymi,
                    "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            String notificationTitle = "Neue Vertretungsstunden!";
            String notificationText = ausgabe + " fällt heute aus";
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Vertretungsplan.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle,
                    notificationText, pendingIntent);

            if (auswertungsergebnis == 1) {
                notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, myNotification);
            }
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to `PendingIntent.getActivity` - that flag needs to be added to the `Intent` itself:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Vertretungsplan.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
```